# Print with Margins While Keeping Aspect Ratio of Image C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, printing

I’m using WinForms. In my Form I got a picuturebox and 4 textboxes margin_top, margin_bottom, margin_left, and margin_right. I want to be able to create margins for the images at appear in the print preview dialog-box, but I also want to scale the image proportionately when I provide the margins. I also want the images to be enclosed in the print-preview-page, meaning not having the images cut-of. Another question, is why my image is cutting of when the print-preview page is the same size as my image? I used an 850 width by 1100 Height image and when I clicked print preview the image it got cut off without me having to re-size it.

Below is a link for an image you can test on.

http://www.filedropper.com/850x1100

[image]

Below is an image that not displaying correctly in the print-preview screen. It is missing its right and bottom borders.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Printing_Image_Center
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Bob\Pictures\850x1100.png");
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        var img_width = e.PageBounds.Width - e.MarginBounds.Left - Math.Abs(e.MarginBounds.Right - e.PageBounds.Width);
        var img_height = e.PageBounds.Height - e.MarginBounds.Top - Math.Abs(e.MarginBounds.Bottom - e.PageBounds.Height);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(ResizeAcordingToImage(pictureBox1.Image, img_width, img_height),
            e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top);
    }

    private void Btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

        //PrintDocument.OriginAtMargins = true;
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = Convert.ToInt32(txt_Top.Text);
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = Convert.ToInt32(txt_Left.Text);
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = Convert.ToInt32(txt_Right.Text);
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = Convert.ToInt32(txt_bottom.Text);

        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }


    private Image ResizeAcordingToImage(Image Source, int boxWidth, int boxHeight)
    {
        Image resizedImage;
        double dbl = (double)Source.Width / (double)Source.Height;
        //set height of image to boxHeight and check if resulting width is less than boxWidth, 
        //else set width of image to boxWidth and calculate new height
        if ((int)((double)boxHeight * dbl) <= boxWidth)
        {
            resizedImage = new Bitmap(Source, (int)((double)boxHeight * dbl), boxHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            resizedImage = new Bitmap(Source, boxWidth, (int)((double)boxWidth / dbl));
        }

        return resizedImage;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide the values of `img.width` and `img.height` in your code to resolve the problem. This is the only thing that you were missing.

```
var img = ResizeAcordingToImage(pictureBox1.Image, img_width, img_height);

e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, img.Width, img.Height);
```

**Here is your result after the changes:**

[image]